# Is is possible to have an image's rollover trigger a different active state for multiple images?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

I would like to create a gallery of images but when one image is clicked on the other images will react to the one that is clicked.

http://thegoodgirlsnyc.com/test/test.html#

I'm failing to find an existing plugin, and I'm not sure where to start.  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question. A live link is fine, but it might rot, and StackOverflow aims to be as self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create it, so I'm working how to do so.

Comment: You've been here for 7 months, you should know we won't write your code for you :) Did you try searching for [existing plugins](http://www.webdesignshock.com/100-best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't complete my question.  Any tips on where to start are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? You could substitue images for background colors if that's what you're trying to acheive.

http://jsfiddle.net/k4t434sispho3nix/Eb9as/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would lend itself excellently for this. You'd take a click listener on the images (One on the parent element might be better (Look for deferred listener if I get that term right)). Then you'd simply add a css class to all images except for the one clicked (Make sure you remove this class from the clicked image if it's there). If you need special styling on the clicked image, add another unique class to that.

After this you can just use a css template file to style the different elements.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I think I can use click events for this.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said in the original post, I believe you'd need something like this:

```
$("#clicked_div_id").click(function(){
   $("#top-left-box").attr("src", "top_right_himage.jpg")
   $("#bottom-right-box").attr("src", "bottom_right_himage.jpg");
});
```